# $.ajax post working in Chrome, but not in Firefox

Tags: jquery, ajax, firefox

Okay, I'll be short. I have this script which is putting values in database. It's working perfect in Chrome, Safari, but can't make it work in Firefox or IE. It seems that data isn't even being posted to .php file and ajax is not starting at all. Anyone, please?

This is my jquery script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#dodaj").click(function(){
  event.preventDefault();
  var kategorija = $("#kategorija option:selected").val();
  var si = $("#si").val();
  var hu = $("#hu").val();
  var de = $("#de").val();
  var an = $("#an").val();
  var hr = $("#hr").val();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "dodaj_v_bazo.php",
    data: {"kategorija": kategorija, "si": si, "hu": hu, "de": de, "an": an, "hr": hr},
    success: function(data){
        alert( "Jed uspešno dodana."+data);
    }, 
});
return false;
});
});
```

This is the content in my php file:

```
$kategorija = $_POST['kategorija'];
$si = $_POST['si'];
$hu = $_POST['hu'];
$de = $_POST['de'];
$an = $_POST['an'];
$hr = $_POST['hr'];

$dodaj_v_bazo = "INSERT INTO jedi (kategorija, si, hu, de, an ,hr) VALUES ('$kategorija', '$si', '$hu', '$de', '$an', '$hr')";
mysql_query($dodaj_v_bazo) or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You didn't define `event` as parameter of the event handler, hence in

```
event.preventDefault();
```

the browser tries to look up `event` in the global scope. Chrome happens to provide the event object in global scope (hence no error) but Firefox doesn't (hence an error).

I'd suggest to add the `event` parameter to the event handler:

```
$("#dodaj").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    // ...
});
```

There is an additional difference: If you don't define the `event` parameter, `event` will refer to the *native* event object in Chrome, which is different than [the event object which jQuery passes to the handler](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/).

To learn more about event handling with jQuery, I recommend to go through [these articles](http://learn.jquery.com/events).

Comment: I am having the same issue. It works in localhost without using `event.preventDefault()` but in aws server, its not working. Any idea why?

Comment: P.S: it worked by adding that. Wonder how its working in localhost without adding `e.preventDefault()`

Answer (score 9):

Async call might not work in FF if you it triggered on form submission. You can add async:false to your ajax call and it will work. It is either that or the fact that you have cross domain call that you will have to fix through CORS.

Answer (score 3):

The Firefox missing the `$ajax` async call has been fixed in the Firefox v49.0.2 and above.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#dodaj").click(function(){
  event.preventDefault();
  var kategorija = $("#kategorija option:selected").val();
  var si = $("#si").val();
  var hu = $("#hu").val();
  var de = $("#de").val();
  var an = $("#an").val();
  var hr = $("#hr").val();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "dodaj_v_bazo.php",
    data: {"kategorija": kategorija, "si": si, "hu": hu, "de": de, "an": an, "hr": hr},
    success: function(data){
        alert( "Jed uspešno dodana."+data);
    }, 
});
return false;
});
});
```

The above code will work when you upgrade to Firefox v49.0.2 or above.