# Ajax post is not working in firefox but its working in chrome

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, asp.net-web-api

I am new in ReactJs I am trying to fetch some data from webAPI AJAX post

My code is working fine in Chrome but in Mozilla fire fox its not working
If I remove headers section in $.ajax api call its working but with header its not. Please help me what I am missing or how it will run in both firefox or chrome.

in my userTypeAPI.js class

```
export const constgetUsertype = (authenticationKey) => {
    return getUsertype(authenticationKey);
};
$.support.cors = true;
function getUsertype(authenticationKey) {
    var returnvalue = '';
    $.ajax({
        url: usertypeURL + "/getUserType",
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.withCredentials = false;
        },
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: false
        },
        crossDomain: true,
        headers: {
            "AuthenticationKey": authenticationKey
        },
        //contentType: 'application/json',
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            returnvalue = data.d;
        },
        error: function (request, error) {
            debugger;
            alert(error);
            returnvalue = "";
        }
    });
    return returnvalue;
}
```

In react.jsx class

```
import * as userTypeAPI from '../UserTypeAPI';


    componentDidMount() {
        var usertypes = userTypeAPI.constgetUsertype(sessionStorage.getItem('AuthenticationKey'));

        this.setState({
            options: usertypes
        });
}
```

In webAPI controller class code is

```
 [RoutePrefix("api/UserType")]
    [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    public class UserTypeController : ControllerBase
    {
        TaskUserType taskUserType = new TaskUserType();

        [HttpPost]
        [ActionName("getUserType")]
        public object getUserType() //Parameter is EntityUserType because we pass UserType information for get list of task
        {
            try
            {
                var requestId = string.Empty;
                var AuthenticationKey = string.Empty;
                var re = Request;
                var headers = re.Headers;
                if (headers.Contains("AuthenticationKey"))
                {
                    AuthenticationKey = headers.GetValues("AuthenticationKey").First();
                }

                long userId = 0;

                if (!Authenticated(AuthenticationKey))
                    return Ok("Unauthorize user");
                else
                    userId = Convert.ToInt64(dtSession.FirstOrDefault().User_Id);

                Dictionary<string, object> returnDict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                List<EntityUserType> lstUserTypes = new List<EntityUserType>();
                lstUserTypes = taskUserType.getAllUserTypes();
                returnDict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                returnDict.Add("d", lstUserTypes);
                return returnDict;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return ex.Message;
            }
        }
   }
```

And config of webAPI is

```
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Overwrite, Destination, Content-Type, Depth, User-Agent, Translate, Range, Content-Range, Timeout, X-File-Size, X-Requested-With, If-Modified-Since, X-File-Name, Cache-Control, Location, Lock-Token, If" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
```

I already check 
[$.ajax post working in Chrome, but not in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18274383/ajax-post-working-in-chrome-but-not-in-firefox) link but here it shows event.preventDefault(); and in my code there is no any event.

Comment: "not working" ... great ... so, in what way doesn't it work? Have you checked Firefox **developer** tools console for errors or other messages? In the developer network tab, is the request made? what's the result of the request?

Comment: `async:false` should never ever be used and you should be seeing warnings about it being deprecated in your console. Use the `$.ajax` promise instead

Comment: Did you already try debugging ? do you see the request going out in your developer tools and if yes do you get a different response in FF and Chrome ? In that case you should also get some kind of error message if anything went wrong. Chances are big that you'll get an error message about synchronous requests on the main thread, as these [have been deprecated on FF ](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests). Try changing `async: false,` to `async: true `, it should do the trick, but then you need to adapt your code for asynch calls.

Comment: `If I remove headers section in $.ajax api call its working but with header its not` looks like the request doesn't "pass" CORS pre-flight - you do know about the OPTIONS request, right? Though, that should me Chrome fails pre-flight too ... unless you've done something tricky with Chrome that you didn't mention

Comment: I already have **developer tool** but it shows only error in error: function (request, error)
 
Regarding console I got "Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:49575/api/UserType/getUserType. (Reason: Multiple CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ not allowed)" worning but I dont know how to resolved it.

Comment: mm sorry but it looks like a syncronos code ..but you're doing an AJAx request ..so it''s ASYNC (i mean js code)

Comment: I already tried to update async: true as well as false but its not working. Even I tried to execute after removing it but same error