# ajax not getting success through firefox but working with chrome and safari as well

Tags: javascript, ajax

Getting error here after post the data but working fine when working with chrome.

```
 $('#submit').on('click', function () {
            var token;
            var objectData =
            {
                username: "admin",
                password: "admin"
            };
            var objectDataString = JSON.stringify(objectData);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "https://localhost:8443/rest/v2/auth/login",
            data: objectDataString,
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function (data) {
                token = JSON.stringify(data);
                console.log("token is :-- "+token);
            },
            error: function () {
               console.log('error..........');
            }
        });
    })
```

Comment: Could you pls share your network tab info. like what the status  code returns while exe this call

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18274383/ajax-post-working-in-chrome-but-not-in-firefox

Comment: what's the error? Don't see any problem and it should really work unless the request is rejected by the server.

Comment: always get error in console that i mention and after change the url path getting the same error so now i an also confused whats going here.

Comment: @Boobalan getting warning :- Strict-Transport-Security: The connection to the site is untrustworthy, so the specified header was ignored.

Comment: @NimeshkaSrimal

Comment: if its work in other browser. it might be a cache problem. Clean your cache and try. Ctrl+Shift+R